# how to deselect a row in RadGrid for windows forms?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview, radgrid

I tried the ClearSelection method, it is deselecting the row but the selected cell is still highlighted

Comment: These kind of questions invariably do poorly at SO.  The intersection of the set of SO users that answer question with the set of users that use 3rd party components is pretty empty.  Use the vendor's support channels, Telerik's support forum is here: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There used to be a bug in that grid which could be circumvented like this:

```
radGridView1.CurrentRow = null;
radGridView1.GridElement.Update(Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridUINotifyAction.StateChanged);
```

Not sure if this will be helpful in your situation though.

Comment: Finally fixed after several months of suffering

Comment: Amazing, looked for this for so long

Answer (score 0):

Tarhini did you tried this datagridview event,

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
foreach(var cell in radGridView1.SelectedCells.ToArray())
{
    cell.IsSelected = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the SelectionMode property of the control. You may have CellSelect while you may need FullRowSelect.